# Creating automatic name verification for GSHEETS

Tags: pygsheets

We have a visitor entry endorsement system through google forms which records responses in a separate gsheet file. In that gsheet file, i put another sheet containing the names of restricted personnel. The gsheet should automatically highlight the names in the responses sheet if they are present in the restricted personnel sheet. I have tried a script that works but unfortunately it works if there are no numbers, period, comma or other symbol involved

Please help in creating a script which would automatically highlight the names of the personnel endorsed for a visit if their name can be found in the restricted personnel sheet. It should be case insensitive and should still run even if there is a number, comma, period, or any other symbol included in the entry

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect, and your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.